# Trouble with onmouseout - Simple drop down menu Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have one table with 1 td and I attached onmouseover event handler on it, which changes the dispay attribute of a div from "none" to "block", and I thought doing  the same thing with  the div - attaching handler to **onmouseout** event which simply changes the display back to "none" will do the trick. Unfortunately when I move the cursor out of the td down to the div the div dissapears when it touches the div border. What the problem? Here's the extremely simple code sample:

```
<table>
<tr>
        <td onmouseover="showMenu()" >BLOCK ONE</td>
    <td>BLOCK TWO</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="box1" onmouseout="hideMenu()">
    <a href="www.abv.bg">www.abv.bg</a><br>
    <a href="www.abv.bg">www.abv.bg</a><br>
    <a href="www.abv.bg">www.abv.bg</a><br>
    <a href="www.abv.bg">www.abv.bg</a><br>
    <a href="www.abv.bg">www.abv.bg</a><br>
    <a href="www.abv.bg">www.abv.bg</a><br>
    <a href="www.abv.bg">www.abv.bg</a><br>

</div>
```

The javascript:

```
 function showMenu() {
var div = document.getElementById('box1');
div.style.display = 'block';

}

function hideMenu() {
var div = document.getElementById('box1');
div.style.display = 'none';

}
```

Comment: Why the "java" tag? What does your question have to do with the Java programming language? I have removed this tag; you will want to learn the difference.

Comment: @EnTrERy Then don't tag it with it, this has absolutely nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onmouseout` on the `DIV` probably fires when you go over an `A`.

You can add `onmouseover="showMenu()"` to the DIV

Comment: May be you could get some inspiration from one of the various tooltips plugins available. They try to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, after fiddling with it a bit (in jsFiddle) I came upon this solution for you:

```
showMenu = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('box1');
    div.style.display = 'block';
}

hideMenu = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('box1');
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Here is a live demonstration of it in jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/KBry6/1/

Comment: Nope The problem is that onmouseout is fired when the cursor hits the child element (in this case some of the links) How to fix it ??